# How to apply a user-defined function to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm using Wolfram | Alpha Pro; I have a function

```
f[n] = 351n^(-0.7);
```

How do I apply it to each element of a list like {2, 9, 22}?

f/@{2, 9, 22} just results in showing {f(2), f(9), f(22)} without calculating the values. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what is possible in W|A Pro, but when it takes real Mathematica syntax, then you should try to define your function as `f[n_]:=351n^(-7/10)`

Answer (score 3):

```
f[n_] = 351 n^(-0.7);

f /@ {2, 9, 22}

(*  {216.066, 75.3941, 40.3284}  *)
```

Or, using a pure function

```
351 #^(-0.7) & /@ {2, 9, 22}

(*  {216.066, 75.3941, 40.3284}  *)
```

In WolframAlpha use the pure function

```
WolframAlpha["351 #^(-0.7)&/@{2,9,22}"]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, this works, thank you so much.